# Insert values in dictionary using regex which includes key in the pattern

Tags: python, regex, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a PDF file so I read each line of the converted text file into a list. I have a predefined list which will be used as keys. I want to create a dictionary with keys from the predefined list and extract the corresponding value.
for example, the file would contain

```
Name  : Luke Cameron 
Age and Sex : 37/Male
Haemoglobin       13.0            g/dL
```

I have got predefined list like
`keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']`

My code is

```
for text in lines:
    rx_dict = {elem:re.search(str(elem)+r':\s+\w+.\s\w+',text) for elem in keys}
```

The output:

```
{'Patient Name': None,
 'Age': None,
 'Sex': None
}
```

Desired output:

```
{'Patient Name': Luke Cameron,
 'Age': 37,
 'Sex': Male
}
```

NOTE: This isn't real data and resemblance is just coincidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
import re

data = """
Name  : Luke Cameron 
Age and Sex : 37/Male
Haemoglobin       13.0            g/dL"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>[^:\n]+):(?P<value>.+)', re.M)

result = {}
for match in rx.finditer(data):
    key = match.group('key').rstrip()
    value = match.group('value').strip()
    try:
        key1, key2 = key.split(" and ")
        value1, value2 = value.split("/")
        result.update({key1: value1, key2: value2})
    except ValueError:
        result.update({key: value})

print(result)
```

Which yields

```
{'Name': 'Luke Cameron', 'Age': '37', 'Sex': 'Male'}
```

Comment: Thanks, there are unwanted white-space and indentation in my file so gotta handle that aswell but it was a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

```
strings_from_pdf = ["Name  : Luke Cameron", "Age and Sex : 37/Male", "Haemoglobin  13.0  g/dL"]
keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']

def findKeys(keys):
    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(strings_from_pdf)):
        if keys[0] in strings_from_pdf[i]:
            _, name = strings_from_pdf[i].split(":")
            dict['Patient Name: '] = name
        if keys[1] in strings_from_pdf[i]:
            _, age_and_gender = strings_from_pdf[i].split(":")
            age, gender = age_and_gender.split("/")
            dict['Age: '] = age
            dict['Gender: '] = gender
    return dict

dict = findKeys(keys)
```

Comment: I am looking for something that would generalise well for I have got around 400 keys. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex approach:

```
txt = """\
Name  : Luke Cameron 
Age and Sex : 37/Male
Haemoglobin       13.0            g/dL"""

keys=('Patient Name','Age','Sex')

ans={}
for t in (line.partition(':') for line in txt.splitlines() if line.partition(':')[2]):
    if sum(n in t[0] for n in keys)>1:
        ans.update(
           {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in zip(t[0].split(' and '), t[2].split('/'))})
    else:
        ans[t[0].strip()]=t[2].strip()

>>> ans
{'Name': 'Luke Cameron', 'Age': '37', 'Sex': 'Male'}
```